# use an object of array

Tags: php, laravel

Actually coding a laravel web app. I made a function which retrieves me some IDs from mysql that I need to work with.

This function returns me an object ( var_dump)

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[335]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[334]
          public 'crschpsup_id' => int 107
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[333]
          public 'crschpsup_id' => int 108
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[340]
          public 'crschpsup_id' => int 235
```

How can I use them one by one, `$myobject->items`   or  `$myobject[0]` as for arrays doesn't work also.

Thanks for help

Comment: So... `$collection->get('items')`?

Comment: `"how can i use them one by one"`.. I would [start here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: `" $myobject->items or $myobject[0] as for arrays doesnt work"`http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/023/021/e02e5ffb5f980cd8262cf7f0ae00a4a9_press-x-to-doubt-memes-memesuper-la-noire-doubt-meme_419-238.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In most cases laravel uses a collection class to work easily with arrays or sets of objects. Rows selected from database, session bag messages, all of them are collections.

Collections can be used in foreach loop as array.

```
foreach($collection as $item)
{
    // do whatever you want with $item
}
```

Of course you can still access `nth` element of collection by using

```
$collection[$nth]
```

or

```
$collection->nth($nth)
```

And remember. Always read documentation before work with something new, before asking, before overthinking things.